# Не скролится RecyclerView с кастомным LayoutManager если вложен в NestedScrollView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Если RecyclerView вложен в NestedScrollview, прокрутка не происходит. При помещении в LinearLayout - прокрутка элеметов нормальная.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              app:behavior_hideable="false"
              app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/ttn_list_peek_height"
              app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/app_background"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Инициализация RecyclerView:

```
MyLayoutManager lm = new MyLayoutManager(mContext);
lm.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
rcHistoryList.setLayoutManager(lm);
rcHistoryList.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
rcHistoryList.setHasFixedSize(false);
rcHistoryList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

LayoutManager распалагает элементы один над другим со смещением - для создания эффекта наложения элементов.

```
public class MyLayoutManager extends RecyclerView.LayoutManager {

  private static final String TAG = "ScrollManager";

  private SparseArray<View> viewCache = new SparseArray<>();

  private Context context;

  private int mAnchorPos;

  public MyLayoutManager(Context context)
  {

  }

  @Override
  public boolean canScrollVertically() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int delta = scrollVerticallyInternal(dy);
    offsetChildrenVertical(-delta);
    fill(recycler);
    return delta;

  }

  private int scrollVerticallyInternal(int dy) {
    int childCount = getChildCount();
    int itemCount = getItemCount();
    if (childCount == 0){
      return 0;
    }

    final View topView = getChildAt(0);
    final View bottomView = getChildAt(childCount - 1);

    int viewSpan = getDecoratedBottom(bottomView) - getDecoratedTop(topView);
    if (viewSpan <= getHeight()) {
      return 0;
    }

    int delta = 0;

    if (dy < 0){
      View firstView = getChildAt(0);
      int firstViewAdapterPos = getPosition(firstView);
      if (firstViewAdapterPos > 0){
        delta = dy;
      } else {
        int viewTop = getDecoratedTop(firstView);
        delta = Math.max(viewTop, dy);

      }
    } else if (dy > 0){
      View lastView = getChildAt(childCount - 1);
      int lastViewAdapterPos = getPosition(lastView);
      if (lastViewAdapterPos < itemCount - 1){ 
        delta = dy;
      } else {
        int viewBottom = getDecoratedBottom(lastView);
        int parentBottom = getHeight();
        delta = Math.min(viewBottom - parentBottom, dy);
      }
    }
    return delta;
  }

  private View getAnchorView() {
    int childCount = getChildCount();
    HashMap<Integer, View> viewsOnScreen = new HashMap<>();
    Rect mainRect = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
      View view = getChildAt(i);
      int top = getDecoratedTop(view);
      int bottom = getDecoratedBottom(view);
      int left = getDecoratedLeft(view);
      int right = getDecoratedRight(view);
      Rect viewRect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
      boolean intersect = viewRect.intersect(mainRect);
      if (intersect){
        int square = viewRect.width() * viewRect.height();
        viewsOnScreen.put(square, view);
      }
    }
    if (viewsOnScreen.isEmpty()){
      return null;
    }
    Integer maxSquare = null;
    for (Integer square : viewsOnScreen.keySet()) {
      if (maxSquare == null){
        maxSquare = square;
      } else {
        maxSquare = Math.max(maxSquare, square);
      }
    }
    return viewsOnScreen.get(maxSquare);
  }

  private void fill(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler) {

    View anchorView = getAnchorView();
    viewCache.clear();

    for (int i = 0, cnt = getChildCount(); i < cnt; i++) {
      View view = getChildAt(i);
      int pos = getPosition(view);
      viewCache.put(pos, view);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < viewCache.size(); i++) {
      detachView(viewCache.valueAt(i));
    }

    fillDown1(recycler);
    fillUp1(recycler);

    for (int i=0; i < viewCache.size(); i++) {
      recycler.recycleView(viewCache.valueAt(i));
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);
    fill(recycler);
  }

  private void fillUp1(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler) {
    boolean fillUp = true;
    int pos = 0; //anchorPos - 1;
    int viewBottom = 0;// = anchorTop;

    while (fillUp && pos >= 0){
      View view = viewCache.get(pos);
      if (view == null){
        view = recycler.getViewForPosition(pos);
        addView(view, 0);
        measureChildWithMargins(view, 0, 0);
        layoutDecorated(view, 0, viewBottom - getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(view), getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view), viewBottom);
      } else {
        attachView(view, 0);
        viewCache.remove(pos);
      }
      viewBottom = getDecoratedTop(view);
      fillUp = (viewBottom > 0);
      pos--;
    }
  }

  private void fillDown1(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler) {
    int pos = 0;
    boolean fillDown = true;
    int height = getHeight();
    int viewTop = 0;
    int itemCount = getItemCount();
    View view1 = recycler.getViewForPosition(getChildCount());
    pos = getChildCount();
    viewTop = getDecoratedTop(view1);
    while (fillDown && pos < itemCount){
      View view = viewCache.get(pos);

      if (view == null){
        view = recycler.getViewForPosition(pos);
        addView(view);
        measureChildWithMargins(view, 0, 0); 
        layoutDecorated(view, 0, viewTop, getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view), viewTop + getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(view));
viewHeight);
      }
      else
      {
        attachView(view);
        viewCache.remove(pos);
      }
      viewTop = getDecoratedBottom(view) - 70;
      fillDown = viewTop <= height;
      pos++;
    }

  }

  @Override
    public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
      return new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Там где инициализируете адаптер, попробуйте :

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

или в xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Comment: Это первое, что я попробовал. Эффекта нет.

Comment: Использовал ваш код. Удалил rcHistoryList.setHasFixedSize(false);
rcHistoryList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); - работает нормально.

Comment: Есть нюанс: NestedScrollView находится внутри CoordinatorLayout, для NestedScrollView задан peekHeight и он установлен в 2/3 высоты экрана. Когда начинаем скролить RecyclerView сначала поднимается NestedScrollView, а потом идет скролинг. В целом с вашими параметрами работает, однако поведение несколько отличается от ожидаемого: в вашем случае при скроле вниз сначала опуcтится NestedScroll, а потом, до конца можно будет проскролить список до первого элемента. Мне нужно, чтобы сначала проскролился список до первого элемента, а потом опустился NestedScroll.